# How to use ftp file path for SQL loader?

Tags: sql-loader

I could not use ftp file path in SQL loader. Help to solve this problem.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'ftp file path' 
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE temp 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS "(col1,col2)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The string following the `INFILE` parameter needs to be the name of a file containing the data.  See the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1008015

If you are trying to make it a dynamic path to a file, you need to specify it on the command line when you call sql-Loader.  In that case see the `DATA` parameter here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_params.htm#i1004682